# Silverstripe: How to add custom css/js from module

Tags: silverstripe

I am building a small module that replaces the default FileField in Silverstripe and changes it into a fancier upload (in the front end). I replace the class through the injector method in Yaml. This seems to be working all right.

However, I need to add some js and css that only has to be included when the specific field is used. I tried the forTemplate method and the constructor of the filefield class, but both do not result in the files being added to the html.

Is there a way to do this?

I am using SS 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add requirements in the CMS by adding the following to your config.yml file, however this will add globally...

```
LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mymodule/css/mymodule.css
  extra_requirements_javascript:
    - mymodule/javascript/mymodule.js
```

Instead including the required source files just within the FormField constructor would include just when this field is shown...

```
Requirements::javascript("mymodule/javascript/mymodule.js");
Requirements::css('mymodule/css/mymodule.css');
```

You can also add code directly possibly including values from the PHP like this...

```
Requirements::customCSS('
    #Form_FilterForm .field {
        display:inline-block;
        width:31%
    }
');
Requirements::customScript('
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //JS Code here
    });
');
```

Or as above but it must be included in the header...

```
Requirements::insertHeadTags("
    <style>
        #Form_FilterForm .field {
        display:inline-block;
        width:31%
        }
    </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        //JS Code here
    });
    </script>
");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was already on to that. Additionally, I made a typo in the script names. That was why it did not show up after I put it in the constructor :(

Comment: There is however an additional caveat with adding the css/js to the config.yml. For that, the module directory name should be fixed, and I think that's less than ideal